# Lost display after nvidia driver update on optimus laptop (everyting else works)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, xserver

I've been using Ubuntu 14.10 with no problems for a couple of months. After fresh install I installed property Nvidia driver(nvidia-331) from software sources and had no problem using it with Nvidia Prime feature. Then I wanted to update my driver to Nvidia 340. I just added `xorg-edgers` ppa to my software sources then after a short time Software Updater told me that updates was available(around 100 mb). I updated, rebooted and changed my GPU to Nvidia using Prime. After logout/login I had nothing on my screen. But the weird part is, my computer works! I can hear system sounds, I can open a terminal and enter commands; but I just can't see what I am doing. Whenever I switch back to Intel HD Graphics and reboot, I get my display back. I tried to install Nvidia 340 via software center(it was still 331 at that time), now I have version 340 but I still have the same problem. I tried `xkill` `xinit` `startx` etc from tty1 but nothing seems to work. I still have no display on discrete Nvidia card. I don't know what to do can anyone help me out?

Sorry for my bad English.

**Update:**
I successfully returned my drivers to their last working state(Nvidia 331 with Prime, tried both cards and they work). I just used `ppa-purge` to purge `xorg-edgers` ppa and it downgraded the packages I installed from this ppa. Here is the command I used:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-nvidia-driver-346-16-beta/

Now I can use Nvidia 331 property drivers but I'm still searching for ways to install Nvidia 340 drivers successfully. I'll update this post again if I find a way to do it.

**Update 2:**
OK, I found a way to install and use newest Nvidia 346 drivers with Nvidia Prime. It seems that the problem is not caused by driver. Something else in the xorg-edgers ppa causes this problem but I don't know what it is.

**Caution:** I'm no expert, I'm just trying things out. I don't know if this will mess my system up in future. Try this if you know what you are doing or warn me if I am doing something wrong.

Here is what I did:

Add xorg-edgers ppa to software sources:

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update

Install driver from ppa:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings

Source: again http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-nvidia-driver-346-16-beta/

And then, I opened Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software and unchecked the http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu entry. Thus it will not install any other packages from this ppa. Now I can use Nvidia 346 drivers with prime and have no problems yet.

Comment: File a bug report with nvidia as it is a closed source driver, remove it, and go back to the open source driver.

Comment: Is this really all I can do? I don't want to go back to the open source driver since it lacks both performance and power saving. I think I'll just keep it as a last option. Still thanks for your fast answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to install and use newest Nvidia 346 drivers with Nvidia Prime. It seems that the problem is not caused by driver. Something else in the xorg-edgers ppa causes this problem but I don't know what it is.

**Caution:** I'm no expert, I'm just trying things out. I don't know if this will mess my system up in future. Try this if you know what you are doing or warn me if I am doing something wrong.

Here is what I did:

Add xorg-edgers ppa to software sources:

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update

Install driver from ppa:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings

Source: again http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-nvidia-driver-346-16-beta/

And then, I opened Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software and unchecked the http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu entry. Thus it will not install any other packages from this ppa. Now I can use Nvidia 346 drivers with prime and have no problems yet.

Answer (score 2):

That's the black screen issue with nvidia-prime, xorg, wayland and the heavy work on these topics during the last year(s).
The most recent cause of that problem is explained herein:

- [Black screen when in nvidia mode after updating to kernel 3.13.0-45](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580693/black-screen-when-in-nvidia-mode-after-updating-to-kernel-3-13-0-45) See the answer from Charl Botha, Feb 2 at 22:15
  This one is an extremely annoying bug.

As a rule of thumb: You always should switch to a virtual console `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and back to your X-console `Ctrl + Alt + F7` (or F8). This will work in many cases. Ater the solution from above I had to do so (once again).

This error has many reasons but most of them are due to corrupt xorg.conf file or bad dkms modules/drivers. Another good point to start with is `Ctrl + Alt + F1; sudo service lightdm stop; sudo prime-switch intel; sudo service lightdm start; Ctrl + Alt + F7` and once on desktop window start the `gksudo/kdesudo nvidia-settings` and save it without clicking anywhere, just quit with saving, reboot an hope.

There are many older (before 2015) solutions to similar problems. All together they relay on the black screen when using nvidia after the boot splashscreen immediately on login screen or after login.

Comment: I've been messing up with Nvidia drivers for a long time(I said a couple of months but it's just my last install, I've been using Ubuntu for 2 years). I had black screen errors before but this is the first time I can use my computer when display is gone. I tried most of these you mentioned but I'll try the rest of them. Thanks for helpful answer!

Comment: I tried this out and ended up with an unbootable system(login loop). So I had to revert it. I solved my problem with some other way and edited my original post. Again, thanks for your help!